# html5 video tag on Android gives black screen

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm trying to setup a mobile website and testing Android devices.  I can get the h264 video to load and play but I have a black screen.  The code is quite simple:

```
<video id='myfileplayer2' src='mysite/mobile/video.mp4' width='280' height='200'  controls></video>
```

Any ideas?

I also tried some javascript as suggested from some searches:

```
var video = document.getElementById('myfileplayer2');
  video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

Comment: Are you sure the browser you're using for testing supports HTML5?

Comment: I'm testing this on Android devices and I use the SDK to try different versions. AFAIK html5 video has been supported for some time. But either way my focus is on 4.0.3 which definitely has support.

Comment: Maybe the video is not encoded properly causing it to stall...did you try to load it inside the browser? Maybe you can post a link to your video or upload it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<style type="text/css">       
    #Video1
    {
     position:fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left:0px;        
     width: 100%;       
     border:0px;
     display:block;
     }

    </style>
</head>
    <body>        
       <video id="Video1" preload="metadata" autobuffer autoplay>
        <source src="5xyz.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="//5xyz.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="//5xyz.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
       </video>

<script>
var Video1 = document.getElementById('Video1');
Video1.addEventListener('click',function(){
  Video1.play();
},false);
</script>
```

This work for me, just click in the black screen. My question is the same of your, how to CHANGE this black screen for some "play button" image.... Anyone?